Visual Studio Code crashes after pushing code to remote repository
I've been using Visual Studio Code along with Git so that I can upload my local repositories to my remote repository on GitHub using the Git Bash terminal.
But every time I do 'Git Push' VS Code proceeds to freeze and then crash (forces the program to close). And when I try to reopen it after forcing it to close, the program repeats the same thing, freezes and closes.
I would appreciate if someone could give me a solution to this. I thought it might be due to some incompatibility of VS Code with Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS. But honestly I'm new to Linux and I have no idea about the subject.

Can you push from a command prompt without using VS Code?

Check for Updates: Make sure Visual Studio Code and Git are up to date. Sometimes, updates can fix compatibility issues.
Disable Extensions: Some extensions might be causing the crash. Try disabling all extensions. You can do this by starting Visual Studio Code with the
code  --disable-extensions flag:

I tried but thats not works, I entered my code but as soon as I entered it it asked me to force close the application

This crash is happening only at the time of push ?

Yes, only when I push. I can make a git add, git commit -m "" and rename the branch to main. But on the moment to push, VS Code crashes

FINALLY I CAN SOLVE
When doing git push -u origin main you will be asked for a user (your GitHub user) and in the password, there will be a token that you have to generate from GitHub. It is generated by going to (in gitHub.com):

Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Tokens > Tokens (classic)

